# Waitpid unknown return type in gdb

Tags: linux, gdb, zombie-process, waitpid

I try to remove zombie processes without killing the parent. I'm inside a debian 11 based container on a k8s instance.
SIGCHLD on parent does not work and naturally SIGKILL, and SIGTERM not working on Zs.

My latest approach is to use the `gdb`. By attaching to the parent process and using the `call waitpid (44,0,0)` command I face the below error:
`'waitpid' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type`

I understand the problem and tried to cast it to `pid_t` in various ways but I was not able to resolve the problem. How am I supposed to correctly cast the call for the gdb to accept it (I'm not interested in the return value, I just want to remove them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I understand the problem and tried to cast it to pid_t
> > Try casting it in int.

```
(gdb) call (int) waitpid(13685, 0,0)
(gdb) detach
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I incorrectly assumed the `pid_t` type based on some documentation.